# Displaying date in a double digit format

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I am having trouble displaying the date in a double digit format.  I want it to be so that when the day or the month is a single digit example: 4  It would display 04.  I'm having trouble coming up with the logic for it, if somebody can help me I would be really grateful.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        if (month % 10 == 0) {

            Place = 0 + month;
        }
        String Dates = year + "-" + Place + "-" + day;
        Date.setText((Dates));
```

Comment: Maybe Place = "0" + month would work as it is stored then as a String?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat mFormat= new DecimalFormat("00");
mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(year));
```

in your case:

```
 mFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
 String Dates =  mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(year)) + "-" +  mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(Place)) + "-" +  mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(day));
```

Comment: This code is great, but for some reason it forcible displays my code as 3/18 instead of 4/18. I dont understand why

Comment: try mFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN); see edited answer.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 13):

Please use SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.println("Date : " + sd1.format(new Date(c.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Output

```
Date : 18-Apr-2012
```

Comment: @GregKopff No, not correct. The Question explicitly asked for the month as a double-digit number not a name-of-month.

Comment: @Basil , then, you can use dd-MM-yyyy instead of dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: @Hatim I suggest you edit your Answer to provide a relevant solution rather than post as a Comment. Then again maybe you shouldn't. Your irrelevant Answer has 13 up-votes and one complement while my own spot-on Answer has one down-vote.

Comment: @Basil, I just posted a comment. this is not my answer

Answer (score 12):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

String Dates = year + "-" +(month<10?("0"+month):(month)) + "-" + day;
Date.setText((Dates));
```

Comment: FYI, the modern *java.time* classes make this much easier: `LocalDate.now().toString()` -> `2018-01-27`

Answer (score 8):

```
if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
    NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
    Sting date = String.valueOf(f.format(dayOfMonth));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use String.format() method.

example :

```
String.format("%02d", month);
```

so they would add "0" in front of month if the chosen month less than 10.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()
         .toString()
```

> 2016-01-07

Better to always specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .toString()
```

## Avoid old date-time classes

The java.util.Calendar class you are using is now legacy. Avoid this class, along with java.util.Date and such. These have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

## java.time

The old date-time classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

These modern classes can accomplish your goal in a single line of code, as seen below.

## Date-time formatting features

Both the old outmoded date-time classes as well as java.time classes offer formatting features. No need for you to be writing your own formatting code.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial to determine the date. The date varies around the world by time zone as a new day dawns earlier in the east. This issue was ignored in the Question and other Answers. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Better to explicitly specify your desired/expected time zone.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). While no time zone is stored within the `LocalDate`, a time zone determines “today”.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

## ISO 8601

Your desired format of YYYY-MM-DD with double digits happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining sensible formats for textual representations of date-time values. This standard is used by default in java.time classes for parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = today.toString();
```

That’s all, 3 lines of code. You could even combine them.

```
String output = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for the stackoverflow time to give you a upvote :)

Answer (score 5):

Purely using the Java 8 Time library:

```
String date = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Actually, the Question asks for entire date, year-month-day.

Comment: Modified my response to account for that. Although I just noticed this is tagged as android and my response was for the standard jdk. Not sure if it will differ.

Comment: Later Android has an implementation of *java.time*. For earlier Android, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Comment: No need to specify that formatting pattern. That format year-month-day is standard ISO 8601 format used by default in the `toString` as explained in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37079498/642706) posted a couple years ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((month+1)<10){
    place = "0"+(String) (month+1)
}
```

do the same for day and you are good to go.

+1 in month because it starts with 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.. There are a lot of ways to do it..

something like this..

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"); // you can add any format..


      Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDate);
```

Comment: This is far more convenient than the accepted answer

Comment: @javadba Actually, this Answer uses confusing troublesome old date-time classes that are now supplanted by the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat class

```
String dates = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").format(new Date())
```

for more information 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, specifically the [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class.

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(new Date());
String month = datetime.toString("MM");
```

result will be 2 digits

If you need for example a year you can use:

```
String year = datetime.toString("YYYY");
```

result will be 4 digits of the year.

Comment: There is no `DateTime` class in Java 8. And not much Java 8 in Android.

Comment: Tks, I changed my text to org.joda.time.DateTime.

Comment: What is the problem with this answer? I already use this in differents context and I never got a problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong now. I imagine the down vote was from before you identified the Joda-Time library as the source of your classes.

Comment: FYI, the *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and further adapted to Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Comment: That's was not fair. This answer responds exactly the purpose of the question. but its ok!

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.datePicker.setOnClickListener {

            val mCurrentDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val mYear: Int = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val mMonth: Int = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val mDay: Int = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

            val mDatePicker = DatePickerDialog(
                requireActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme,
                { datepicker, selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday ->
                    val selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1

                    val mFormat = DecimalFormat("00")
                    mFormat.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN
                    val date: String =
                        mFormat.format((selectedyear)) + "-" + mFormat.format((selectedmonth)
                        ) + "-" + mFormat.format((selectedday))

                    binding.edtDob.setText(date)

                }, mYear - 18, mMonth, mDay - 1
            )
            // set maximum date to be selected as today
            // age more then 18+
            mCurrentDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
            mCurrentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)
            mDatePicker.datePicker.maxDate = mCurrentDate.timeInMillis
            mDatePicker.show()
            
        }
```

> **However, you only require this part.**

```
 val mFormat = DecimalFormat("00")
 mFormat.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN
 val date: String = mFormat.format((selectedyear)) + "-" + mFormat.format((selectedmonth)) + "-" + mFormat.format((selectedday))
  binding.edtDob.setText(date)
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation?

Comment: What do you want to know more about?